# How to get the String of a php print?

Tags: java, android, http

I set up a basic http url connection. It is linked to a php file on a server. But instead of getting the print content i get some sort of html data.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_string);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        if( conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ){
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            String result = convertStreamToString(is);
            Log.d("debugLog", "Data from server: " + result);
            callback.gotSQLResult(new JSONArray(result));
        }else{
            InputStream err = conn.getErrorStream();
            Log.e("SQLConnector", convertStreamToString(err));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The result that i get from logcat is:

```
Data from server: <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("b10df586fe460659e620a68a3df26a1c");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://eventmanagerapp.byethost11.com/sqlconnector/get_drinks.php?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

How can i obtain only the String of the php print?

Do i have to enable Javascript for this to work? How could i do that if i had to?

Comment: You got a html page telling you to enable javascript. If you could enable javascript you would probably receive a normal html page. So what do you mean with 'string' or 'string on the page'?

Comment: consider removing `php` as the question is not related to php

Comment: This has nothing to do with your query - just the content on the remote page requires js in order for it to work. Please post the here the page you are trying to load for me to be able to assist you in solving your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. This is the file / content i want to get: http://eventmanagerapp.byethost11.com/sqlconnector/get_drinks.php

Comment: Can you please print url_string, please post some logs.

Comment: I am sorry but there are not really more logs. Please tell me if i should log you something specific. url_string is fine (i logged it previously. see comment above for link/content). The only only information about it is the entire response. I will edit the Data from server line in the question so that it has the entire response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem caused by byet.host. Made an awardspace.net account and copied all of the files.

Everything works now. Code is fine!